# Android always wanting to create database

Tags: android, database

I'm working on a small Android database application (I'm an Android newbie).  I have an existing sqlite3 database created on a different platform.  When I use it my SQLiteOpenHelper always calls OnCreate (which of course fails).  When I let Android create the Database all works just fine - OnCreate is called for the first time, but not subsequently.

The android_metadata table is present with local=en_US.

What's going on?

Comment: How can you import an existing database to Android system?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by different platform , do you mean different android application ? If thats the case and you need to use it in this application, you would have to expose your database like a content provider to this application.

@xandy If you are doing Android development on eclipse platform then do the following.

goto  DDMS --> File Explorer --> data -->data --> Your application --> create database folder if not exists.

Then there is an option for "Push a file to this device" push your database file in that. :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: By different platform, I'm creating the database using Delphi, then copying the sqlite3 database to the android emulator.